# Can't push to new repo : The folder pushed differ in case

Tags: git, azure, tfs

Before diving in the question, a little background:

A couple months ago, my team migrate our repo from Team Foundation Server to Azure DevOps.
Last week, we noticed that one branch on the TFS had work done on it which is now needed. So we decided to bring that branch to Azure in order to avoid doing the said work again.

I cloned the repo from TFS on my machine, change the url of origin to match the one of Azure and then tried to push the branch with the following steps :

1. Clone from TFS
2. Create a new branch from the branch I'm interested in
3. Add a remote origin (called origin-azure)
4. Add a dummy file and committed the change
5. Push the branch to origin-azure

It gave me the following error message :

`error: remote unpack failed: error The tree object 1234 was rejected: The folder 'myfolder' and the folder 'MyFolder' pushed differ in case. You must remove or rename one of them or disable case-enforcement (see https://aka.ms/git-platform-compat). To https://urlOfRepoOnAzure ! [remote rejected]     ExportBranche -> ExportBranche (The tree object 5678 was rejected: The folder 'myfolder' and the folder 'MyFolder' pushed differ in case. You must remove or rename one of them or disable case-enforcement (see https://aka.ms/git-platform-compat).) error: failed to push some refs to https://urlOfRepoOnAzure`

I deleted the folder "myfolder" and tried again. Same error.
But I'm able to push to TFS wihtout any problems at all.

I don't understand what's going on. Especially why the push to Azure is rejected since I'm pushing a new branch.

Comment: This is a special feature that Microsoft added to their system. No normal Git notices or cares. The fact that a normal Git doesn't notice or care *is a problem for Windows users* (not always, but often enough to be a concern), which is why they added this feature. If this feature is getting in the way of you doing your work, and you're happy to let Windows folks suffer if they get into trouble, just turn off the feature.

Comment: HI @torek,

I made sure the folder as the same name and case on the remote repo and on the local one, but I still get the error.
Moreover if I make a ```find myfolder``` no results is returned. So I should not have any problem to push to the remote as the folder has the same name on both side.

Comment: The problem is not in your working tree. It is in some *commit* that you're uploading. Remember that GIt doesn't store files; Git stores *commits* (which then store files). Each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file. You have some commits that have uppercase names and some commits that have lowercase names, and that's what the special feature Microsoft added detects.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @torek! I forgot what really is a commit!
Still, with the feature toggled off, I was not able to push to the new origin (still the error). We ended up using the same solution than @WaitingForGuacamole presented.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to deal with the issue. The newfangled `git filter-repo` might have some feature for this as well, or could have one added: it has the right kind of insight to be able to figure this out, and being a Python program, making it do that should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @BernardoDuarte that you should be able to change the policy about case enforcement, but if it's not working, I would try to get out of the way of the whole conflict by doing a more manual update:

1. Clone the TFS repo into a brand new folder
2. Checkout the branch you wish to migrate from (A)
3. Clone the Azure DevOps repo into a *different* brand new folder
4. Create a topic branch (B)
5. Copy all of the folders EXCEPT myFolder from (A) to (B)
6. Open myFolder in (A), and copy all of its contents to myFolder in (B)
7. `git status` in (B) to make sure that the folder case of myFolder is the same as it is in the Azure DevOps repo.
8. Commit and push your topic branch to (B)
9. Pull request your topic branch in Azure DevOps, and then complete it.

If you overwrite myFolder itself, Git will track that as a change and try to push it. This approach, while admittedly clumsy, prevents that change from ever happening, and should bypass the issue.

Comment: Hi @WaitingForGuacamole,

It's what we ended up doing this morning to resolve the error and that worked fine :)

Thank you for your answer ;)

Comment: Wish it were easier!

Comment: Well, after reading the response of @torek to the initial post, It seems to be an older commit that is sending everything to hell.
So I assume it would be possible to remove the said commit from the history and get something clean to push to the new remote.

Maybe not easier but seems more fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can try following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#view-and-edit-repository-settings) and change your repository settings on Azure Repos regarding your Policies about Case enforcement.

Comment: Hi @Bernardo Duarte

I already tried playing with this setting, but without any luck.
I alos tried to rename the folder "myfolder" to a different name with ```git mv -f ``` but I get the error "fatal: bad source"